# How does WordPress link images to the 'page' post type in the db?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

How does `WordPress` link images to the 'page' `post type` in `MySQL`?
Is there a particular key in the `wp_posts` table?

When I save the data in the description field of the page it is stored in the `database` in a serialized manner, e.g. in `wp_posts` under `post_content` field.

So my task is to delete all the images which are neither used by post/pages. And I don't know how to check if page is using any attachments.

When I attach an image in page description it is not updated in `WordPress` besides `wp_content` in a serialized manner but when you attach an image to a post in the custom field then it can be identified in the `database`.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Haven't you asked that question some days ago? What have you tried in between to find some information?

Answer (score 0):

Images are saved to their own custom post type called `attachment`. To be able to know attachment's associated post, you'd need to check for `post_parent` in `prefix_posts` table.

The Column `post_parent` will have the ID of the post which the attachment was uploaded to. If the ID is 0 then it is not associated to a specific post.

You might make use of the function `wp_get_post_parent_id( $post_ID );` to get the attachment parent, haven't tested but seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes you are correct. But what about the images which are added to the description section of pages? There is no linking for that in the database. If I delete the image whose parent is 0 but what if the same image is assigned to page?

Comment: any help on the issues that I am facing?

Comment: This needs some research, you'd have to do that part on your own and provide a sample code that we can maybe improve and correct, I won't be able to research a complete solution for you.